# the difference between field $F_{2^k}$ and ring $Z_{2^k}$ in multi-party computation, especially in SPDZ family

Tags: multiparty-computation

I have seen different protocols in field or ring, I used to think ring is a special field when 2^k. But when I read the paper later, I doubted my understanding.